# How to stream mkv file using html/javascript?

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, mkv

Is there any way to stream mkv files on webpage using javascript/html or any other technologies? I found many questions about this, but I really want to know the answer - is this possible in any way? Maybe ajax, javascript, php, html? Maybe some external libraries? Anything?

I was wondering how youtube works. Is there possible to upload mkv file? Is so, how that videos are streaming to end user?

I know that browser doesn't support mkv natively, but maybe is some way to forcing html to do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube most probably works using the DASH protocol format. On the server side, the source audio and source video are separately divided into segments of different bitrate/quality. A manifest keeps an index of all possible segments values and their location. This allows to switch quality during playback in the player.

On the client side, the DASH (should be the same with the other main technology: HLS) manifest is used by the player to locate the segments to load in order to feed the content in two separate [SourceBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer), one for audio and one for video and both are being played synchronously together in the [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). For an example player that handles this, see the [Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/) developed by Google.

Conclusion, there is no need to use a container like mkv but each channel (video, audio) needs to point to a browser supported codec encoded segments.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need anything special for streaming pre-recorded media files.  A normal HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 server will work just fine.  The browser is generally capable of seeking into the file using range requests.

Matroska (MKV) is a container format, and it actually is widely supported because it's basically the same as WebM.  WebM is a subset of Matroska... the key differences being that there are suggested codecs for use.  (Matroska itself supports almost anything.)

Your audio and video tracks in the file can use a variety of codecs... the key is to use codecs compatible with browsers.  Opus for audio and VP8 for video will take you far.

From there, simply reference your video file in a `<video>` tag.